# Compare date object to difficult string

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, spservices

Issue is that I have one value that is returned by

```
$(this).attr("ows_Modified"); //(Sharepoint and SPService thing)
```

This value seems to be string `'Fri Oct 19 2012 13:35:45 GMT+0200'` need to compare it to the date object with value format like this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()-31);
//2012-10-19 12:14:13
```

and check with one is newer.
Any ideas how to do this please ?

Comment: *"I'm not JS dev and have one time task."* If you're not a JS developer, then perhaps you should hire one for your one-time task.

Comment: ...I guess why would you do that when someone will do your task for you for free? People really need to stop answering these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse both dates with [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), it will understand both formats and then you can compare them.

After importing the library you can use

```
date1 = Date.parse(Fri Oct 19 2012 13:35:45 GMT+0200);
date2 = Date.parse(2012-10-19 12:14:13); // or whatever date
isGreater = date1.isAfter(date2);
```

As gdoron stated, you don't *need* date.js, but it may be worth taking a look, especially if you are likely to manage weird looking date formats or make tricky operations.

Comment: Why won't you use Date which understand them both as well...?

Comment: True, just in case he wants to parse some other formats or simplify tricky operations, but he doesn't need it. I'll specify.

Comment: alemangui - Thanks this helped. I really do appreciate that. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
var isBigger = new Date($(this).attr("ows_Modified")) > new Date().getDate()-31;
```